# Good C++ book about (Unit) Testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++-6

I looked and searched the web but could not found one book dedicated to Testing in C++. They are all more or less Java related with p.s. like examples should be easy converted to C++...
I would really appreciate a book on C++ Unit Testing and maybe a good book on general testing in C++.

Comment: A good place to start looking for information is here: www.testingfaqs.org

Comment: Presumably there are no books on tested that use C++ as their example because only real men code in C++ and real men don't need to write tests!  ;-)

Comment: No books? Isn't this a bit weird? And with C++! It's not like its a 2 years old language :(

Comment: [Modern C++ Programming with Test-Driven Development: Code Better, Sleep Better](http://amzn.com/1937785483)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a book but you might find interesting things in Boost::Test.
See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html to get more information and follow a tutorial on Boost's Unit Test framework.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not on Google, I reckon it must not exist.

One more testing framework I recomend is [CUTE](http://r2.ifs.hsr.ch/cute), which is very easy to use

Comment: CUTE looks like its connected with Eclipse :(